# Why does mapping <esc> cause arrow keys to fail in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard

When I do

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>`^
```

in vim, the next time I switch to insert mode (after using <kbd>Esc</kbd>) the arrow keys fail to move the cursor (they insert letters instead). Why does that happen?

---

**Edit**: It is possible to remap <kbd>Esc</kbd> and still retain working arrow keys?

Answer (score 6):

The underlying code associated with an arrow key is an escape sequence beginning with `<Esc>`. For example, the up arrow key, if I remember right, is sending `<Esc> [ A`.